# How to open a file from apache2 in VS Code using 'code .'

Tags: visual-studio-code, server, apache2, apache2-module

I am using apache2 server where I have my Git repo cloned. I want to be able to open the folder in VS Code using `code .` but when I run that command it says `-bash: code: command not found` -  Do I have to install a package on the server and if so, where would I need to install it. Many thanks.

Comment: is all this being done on your local machine? cuz apache has no relation with VS code

Comment: @DiegoVelez no the clone is being done on the server and not locally. If you do `cat` followed by a file name, it opens up on the terminal but there should be a way for it to open up on VS code surely

Comment: VS code is a local developmement tool. if you want to see the filed you will need to download the files to your machine and run `code .` in the folder

Comment: @DiegoVelez i found a way to do this using a VS code extension called Remote-SSH which let's me open any files on the server in VS Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help which is really appreciated. Anyone who comes across this problem, I simply downloaded the Remote-SSH extension in VS code which allowed me to do open the files on the server directly in the code editor and edit as normal.